# How can I make this Perl Script run Multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have to submit a class project for a perl script that run in a multithread and validates MX record against a list. I think I have the script ready but I just don't know how to implement multithreading to make it run, for example, in 50 threads. Kindly examine script below and help. SO basically, what I want it to do is to make the script run in a multithreaded way to speed it up and make it complete faster.
Your help is very much appreciated.

Edit: solved

Comment: Instead of reaching for threads, I think it's better to use the parallel API of `Net::DNS` as shown in the examples, https://metacpan.org/source/NLNETLABS/Net-DNS-1.18/demo/mresolv etc.

Comment: I don't see you using any threads in your code, could you post the specific part with which you have an issue?

Comment: @Adonis I don't really have an issue with the code itself. Running the code works BUT in just one instance. So if I have a database of say 200,000 entries, you can imagine how long it would take to go through it? If I am able to make the code run as a multi thread, say for example, 10 threads, then it would shorten the time to one-tenth. The issue is how do I add multithread. I went over some multithreading manuals and documents but it's so complex for me. Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow deals mainly with specific coding issues, not with the creation of new features...

Answer (score 2):

When I get home, I'll write a better manual. Including code excerpts

- Step 1: Create a sequence with all important calls as a separate function
- Step 2: Use the function from step 1 to create the individual threads and specialize this function with the individual parameters
- Step 3: After the sequence is finish detach the thread.

Maybe do Step 2 as a Loop/Daemon

---

Here you can read something about threads and how do you use them in your code.

[mathematik.uni-ulm.de - English Tutorial Modul threads](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/help/perl5/doc/perlthrtut.html)

The Perldoc have a good example too:

[perldoc - threads](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reference materials. I will go through while I await your manual.